# React Hook form controller property includes is not assignable to type never

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I am building a form with dynamic fields and I am trying to get over a TS error that says a type string is not assignable to type never.

```
<Controller
  control={control}
  name={`${category}` as const}
  render={({ field: { value, onChange } }) => (
    <Stack gap={1.5}>
      {filterObj?.[category as keyof typeof filterObj]?.map((item) => (
        <Checkbox
          onChange={() => {
            onChange(value ? [...value, item] : [value].filter((v) => v !== item))
          }}
          checked={value?.includes(item)} <-- throws an error
          label={item}
          key={item}
        />
      ))}
    </Stack>
  )}
/>
```

The line where i am checking to if the value is checked is throwing the error

> Property 'includes' does not exist on type 'never'.

I tested `item: any` on the map function, but then it says type any is not assignable to never. I am not sure what I am missing here. Any hints?